# OpenLayers sending flipped BBOX coordinates when using custom projection

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, openlayers, wms, extents

Following the documentation found [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html), I've been trying to create an OpenLayers map view using a custom projection, [EPSG:4674](https://epsg.io/4674) to be more specific. My current code looks like this:

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4';
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj';

proj4.defs('EPSG:4674','GEOGCS["SIRGAS 2000",DATUM["Sistema_de_Referencia_Geocentrico_para_las_AmericaS_2000",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6674"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4674"]]');
register(proj4);
const SIRGAS2000 = getProjection('EPSG:4674');

const map = new Map({
  view: new View({
    projection: SIRGAS2000
...
```

and those are my layers, in my GeoServer instance:
[image: GeoServer layers]

The problem happens whenever I try to load any WMS source using the following code:

```
import { Tile as TileLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { XYZ as XYZSource, TileWMS as TileWMSSource } from "ol/source";

const estadoLayer = new TileLayer({
  title: "Estado",
  source: new TileWMSSource({
    url: GEOSERVER_WMS_URL,
    params: { LAYERS: "postgis:estado", TILED: true },
    projection: SIRGAS2000,
  }),
});
```

OpenLayers sends reversed BBOX coordinates to my GeoServer, as you can see here:
[image: Reversed coordinates]

The funny thing is: If I remove the `projection` attribute from `TileWMS` constructor and set `View`'s projection to `"EPSG:4326"`, everything works fine:

[image: Normal coordinates]

What could be causing this issue? Considering that EPSG:4674 should, in theory, be compatible with EPSG:4326.

Comment: The official registry epsg.org defines the axis order as Lat Lon https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4674  OpenLayers is aware that WMS 1.3.0 uses Lat Lon for EPSG:4326 but for custom projection you need to specify the axis order in the proj4 definition.  Alternatively you could use WMS 1.1.0 which like epsg.io always assumes Lon Lat order.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks for pointing it out! I've definetely overlooked it! So... about proj4 axis order, how could I change that? I Googled it for a while but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: If you use the proj4js definition format simply add `+axis=neu` to the definition. I'm not familiar with proj4 use of WKT format but you could try `AXIS('Geodetic latitude', NORTH),AXIS('Geodetic longitude', EAST)`